# Okta - Retrieving Access Token

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, okta, implicit-grant

This might be a newbie question but I couldn't find any answers to this on SO or Okta forums/guides. I've configured my Okta app to redirect to `https://localhost:443/auth/callback` when a user signs in and grants consent to a scope. I'm using implicit grant and the redirect works but in my `/auth/callback`, the request query, headers, and body doesn't contain the access token. It's only when I call `res.end()` that Express redirects to the below URL:

```
https://localhost/auth/callback#access_token=accessTokenHere&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=openid+phone&state=myState
```

How do I retrieve the access token? My express route:

```
router.get('/auth/callback', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.headers);  // no access token here
    console.log(req.body);  // {}
    console.log(req.body); // {}
    res.end(); // redirects to https://localhost/auth/callback#access_token=accessTokenHere&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=openid+phone&state=myState
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because, what comes after `#` in the URL is called `URI fragment identifier` and it won't be sent to the server it's used in the browser and can be accessed via `window.location.hash`

Instead of `#` you can use `?` (and keep the part after it as it is) which called `query parameters` and can be accessed via `req.query.query_name`, in your case `query_name` is access_token, token_type, expires_in...

Comment: thanks! looks like Okta won't send the token in query params if using implicit grants though so had to redirect to an html page/route. thanks for putting me on the right path though!

Answer (score 0):

The [responseMode][1]

[1]: https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js#responsemode-1 could be set to one of these values: fragment, form_post, query or okta_post_message.
Ref: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#request-parameters